# Laravel seeds wrong id values in many to many relations

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I currently learn Laravel 5.8 and created database where `users` can have two roles: `admin` or `user` stored in `roles` table. I tried to populate `role_users` intermediate table but Laravel doubles rows and seeds wrong data like this: [Crazy ROLE_USER Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FmNP.png).  `role_id` should be only 1 or 2. `user_id` should be unique. What did I do wrong?

User model:

```
public function roles() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'role_users')->withTimestamps(); 
}
```

Role model:

```
public function roles() { 
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'role_users')->withTimestamps();
}
```

create_role_users_table migration:

```
Schema::create('role_users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

RoleUsersFactory factory:

```
$factory->define(RoleUser::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'role_id'   => Role::all()->random()->id,
        'user_id'   => User::all()->random()->id,];
});
```

RoleTableSeeder seeder:

```
$role_user = new Role();
$role_user->role = 'user';
$role_user->save();
$role_admin = new Role();
$role_admin->role = 'admin';
$role_admin->save();
```

DatabaseSeeder seeder:

```
$this->call(RoleTableSeeder::class);
factory(User::class, 5)->create()->each(function($user) {
    $user->roles()->save(factory(RoleUser::class)->make());   
});
```

Comment: Why are your relationships defined as a BelongsToMany when you only want a user to have a single role? The user should have a `belongsTo` and the role should have `hasMany`.

Comment: Could You show me how to do this migrations because I tried different options with `attach()` and `role_user` was empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a role then.

```
$role = Role::create(['role_name' => 'admin']);
```

use `attach()`

```
factory(User::class, 100)->create()->each(function ($user) use ($role ) {
        $role ->users()->attach($user);
});
```

Try the above code.

This will create 100 different users with admin as role. 
you can add other roles like this.

hope this suite for you.

Comment: And now tell me how to do it with factories, because I want to create 100 users. :D

Comment: 100 users for each admin & user or all together 100?

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong relationships (you state that you want all the users to have a single role, which should be a BelongsTo / HasMany).

On the `User` model, have this method:

```
public function role() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Role');
}
```

Create this method on the `Role` model:

```
public function users() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\User');
}
```

Delete the migration you made where the `role_users` table is created and create a new migration with the following code:

```
Schema::table('users', function(Blueprint $table) {
    // remove the nullable if a user HAS to have a role at all times
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id')->nullable();
}
```

Now, as a last step, the seeders. Your Role-seeder is correct. You shouldn't change that. Change your User-seeder to the following:

```
factory(User::class, 100)->create(['role_id' => Role::all()->random()->id]);
```

This will create a database with 100 users, where each has a role of admin or normal user. You can get all the users attached to a role with `$role->users` and get the role of a user with `$user->role`.